# Минимальное пропущенное число

Tags: java

Решаю на Java следующую задачу:

(Условие уточнили после моих вопросов, навеянных общением с пользователями).
Необходимо найти минимальное натуральное число, которого нет во входном массиве.

На вход подается строка, содержащая целые числа в диапазоне от -10^9 до 10^9, разделенные пробелом. На выходе ожидается одно число, удовлетворяющее условию задачи.

Код немного переписал:

```
import java.util.*;

public class hh1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //int[] arr = {7, 3, 12, 5};
        //int[] arr = {6, 9, 5, 2, 3};
        int[] arr = {8, 6, 9, 81, -1000000001};
        if (arr==null) System.out.println("");
        else {
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
            Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                set.add(arr[i]);
            }

            for (Integer integer : set) {
                list.add(integer);
            }
            Collections.sort(list);


            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                if (i + 1 >= list.size()) break;
                if (list.get(0) > 1 || list.get(0) < 0) {
                    System.out.println(1);
                    break;
                }
                if ((list.get(i + 1) - list.get(i)) > 1) {
                    int i1 = (list.get(i + 1) - list.get(i)) - 1;
                    System.out.println(list.get(i + 1) - i1);
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пример:

> Массив 6, 9, 5, 2, 3, 1 сортируем по возрастанию - 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9.
>   Минимальный целый пропущенный элемент больше нуля это 4.

Исправил с учетом советов пользователей и отрицательных чисел(проходит на один тест больше, но 6 шт. из 29 не проходит, как тестируется мне не показывает).
Возможно, я что-то не учел.

Как бы ее еще погонять?

Где ошибка?

Comment: если я правильно понял вашу задачу, то какой результат должен быть при массиве `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`?

Comment: Какой должен быть вывод? Просто число 5?

Comment: Возможно, ноль тоже считается за положительное.

Comment: Вывод одно число. Минимальный пропущенный элемент последовательности. В массиве 8, 6, 9, 81 - это 1. Последовательность здесь начинается с единицы. 6, 9, 5, 2, 3, 1 - вывод 4.

Comment: Как может быть вывод 4?

Comment: массив 6, 9, 5, 2, 3, 1 сортируем по возрастанию - 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9. Минимальный целый пропущенный элемент больше нуля это 4. В моем случае я также удаляю повторяющиеся элементы.

Comment: Кстати, зачем эта строчка - ``if (i+1>=list.size())break;``? Можно же просто сделать цикло до предпоследнего элемента - ``for (int i = 0; i < list.size()-1; i++)``

Comment: Согласен насчет до предпоследнего элемента)

Comment: А какие ограничения в задаче? Могут ли в массиве быть отрицательные числа, или может ли быть массив размера 1?

Comment: По поводу если нет пропущенных элементов и ограничения уточняю

Comment: Необходимо найти минимальное натуральное число, которого нет во входном массиве.

На вход подается строка, содержащая целые числа в диапазоне от -10^9 до 10^9, разделенные пробелом. На выходе ожидается одно число, удовлетворяющее условию задачи.

Comment: Добавил следующее условие:   
                `if (list.get(0) > 1 || list.get(0) < 0) {System.out.println(1); break;}`

Comment: Почему тестирование не проходит? На каких данных вы тестировали? Где код, который тестирует?

Comment: Там если просто вывести в консоль 1, 20 тестов из 29 пройдет)

Answer (score 2):

С java знаком плохо, предложу такой псевдокод

```
Создать массив содержащий все элементы входного массива без дубликатов и превышающие 0, отсортированные по возрастанию.
//Насколько я понял, первая половина вашей программы делает примерно это

Если массив пуст, то
  Вывести 1
  Завершить.

Перебрать все элементы массива по очереди.
  Если значение элемента больше чем индекс + 1 то
    Вывести индекс + 1
    Завершить.

Если массив закончился, то вывести кол-во элементов + 1
```

Comment: Внес правку про элементы меньше или равные нулю.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в том, что если во входном массиве будет отрицательное число X, то ваш алгоритм выдаст X+1.

```
int[] arr = {8, 6, 9, 81, -5};
```

Результат: -4. А должно быть 1.

Comment: элементы массива натуральные числа.

Comment: В условии этого нет.

Comment: да вы правы....

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class min3 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeSet<Long> hs=new TreeSet <>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    
    boolean f= false;
    long count=1;

    try {
    while (in.hasNextLong()) {
        long a=in.nextLong();
            if(a>0) hs.add(a);
    } ;
    //int count=hs.iterator().next();


    for(Long e: hs) {
        if (count!=e) 
        {
            System.out.print(count);
            f=true;
            break;
        };
    count++;
    };
    }
    catch(Exception e) {};
    if(!f)System.out.print(count);
    //System.out.print(hs);
}
```

}